# Run Xcode Instruments on device with a ios keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-instruments, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm developing a custom keyboard but it's very slow and sometimes it's crashing.

Because I'm not sure where it comes from, I'd like to **Time Profiler** with **Instruments**. But when I select MyIphone > Keyboard Extension (target), I get:

> Target failed to run

or

> Waiting for x.x.x.Keyboard
>
> Please take appropriate action to initiate the launch of 'x.x.x.Keyboard.'

---

Is it even possible to use Instruments with an app extension? If yes, how should I proceed?

Comment: select your target after that your timer profile

Comment: @SaurabhJain I don't understand, I already selected my keyboard as a target in time profiler.

Comment: May be this is not possible

Answer (score 3):

I can't use Instruments to analyze my keyboard before, however my method might be helpful to you.

1. Run the project on your iPhone.
2. Xcode the left column, the seventh button 'Show the Debug navigator', select the 'Memory' column.
3. In the right 'Memory Report', select 'Profile in Instruments' in the upper right corner. Instruments will open.

I used this method to enter the Instruments tool to analyze the memory. I noticed that the software name displayed on the Instruments tool was followed by a number, like `com.xxx.xxx.keyboard (4489)`.

Accessing Instruments directly from `Xcode->Product->Profile` does not work properly. This may be the key.

Hope this helps you.