# iOS custom keyboard app extension UICollectionView not scrolling smoothy

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

I'm building a custom keyboard, I'm trying to recreate the **iOS emoji keyboard**. So I created a `UICollectionView` and each cell contains an emoji (`UILabel`).

But it's not scrolling smoothy. I don't know if it comes from the `UICollectionView` of something else.

- Emojis are in a `plist` file, I open it in `viewDidLoad`
- I'm using a xib cell file for my `UICollectionViewCell` (since there is no other way with a custom keyboard)
- I made a test by removing the `UILabel` from the `UICollectionViewCell` and it's still not scrolling smoothy

Any clue?

---

**EDIT**

```
var emojis=[[String]]()

override func awakeFromNib(){
    dataSource=self
    delegate=self

    let nib=UINib(nibName: "EmojiKeyCell", bundle: nil)
    register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! EmojiKeyCell
    let emoji=emojis[indexPath.section][indexPath.item]
    cell.emojiKey.text=emoji
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you post your collection view code? Specifically your `cellForItem(at:)` function?

Comment: @nathan Just added it

Comment: Try running the profiler (`Cmd + i`) to see where your bottleneck is. And add spaces before and after your assignments `dataSource = self` instead of `dataSource=self`. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: @nathan Actually I tried and did not succeed. I asked another question for this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513051/run-xcode-instruments-on-device-with-a-ios-keyboard-extension